# Is there a way to modify the indentation style of Rails templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If a user really want to take the advantage of tab. Is there a way to set code indentation style of Rails permanently?
It will be great if I could just edit some config file to achieve it.

For example, when I'm using scaffold "rails generate scaffold Articals name:string", the auto-generated code is 4-space-indented styled. So that I don't need to use the editor to convert them manually every time.

I'm not asking a programming or syntax question. Rails is not a language. This is all about settings and config. Or I can write a program to auto convert them in background(not a best practice).

If Rails really can't do it, will the team add it in future?

Comment: Actually, no it's not. The rails generator doesn't use \t, but 2 spaces. I remember looking into this before when i first started learning ruby, since i used 4 space in Java, PHP, etc. Most people in the ruby community use 2 spaces. It takes a little getting used to, but i use it for pretty much everything now.

Comment: @CodeGnome : But I don't want to use the editor to convert them manually every time. And I also need to work with other languages at the same time. Repeatedly switching the style is not a good idea.

Comment: @CodeGnome : sorry for my poor English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the OP has updated the question to address modifying the scaffolding templates, and not just indentation styles, the following links might be a useful starting point.

- http://asciicasts.com/episodes/216-generators-in-rails-3 (see "Customizing Templates" section at bottom)
- http://zigzag.github.com/2010/01/18/customizing-your-scaffold-template-become-easier-in-rails3.html

You can also refer to [Creating and Customizing Rails Generators & Templates](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html) for additional guidance on how to modify core templates.

Comment: This is way too much work only to set a different indentation style.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no setting. Most generators run off of templates, and those templates are themselves written by developers with mostly 2 spacing for tabs.

You asked: "Or I can write a program to auto convert them in background."

Yes! in fact, you could do so in Ruby... Something that would look at all new files in git and replace four and two spaces with tabs. Probably only if the line begins with four and/or 2 spaces, but still.

Comment: In addition, 2 spaces for indentation is the [Rails coding convention](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/contributing_to_ruby_on_rails.html#follow-the-coding-conventions), so it's unlikely they will do much work in this area.

Comment: Generators and templates can be modified. It may not be a good idea, but it's certainly possible.